# How can I pretty print keys and values of a JavaScript object on web page

Tags: javascript, json, pretty-print

I have a JavaScript object that contains terms and definitions. I want to create a function that displays/prints the key, value pairs on a webpage.

**For example:**

```
let dict = {
    term1: "definition",
    term2: "definition",
    term3: "definition",
    term4: "definition"
}
```

**Ideal output:**

**term1:** definition

**term2:** definition

**term3:** definition

**term4:** definition

**I am currently using this code:**

```
function viewAll()
{
var json = JSON.stringify(dict,null,3);
document.getElementById("output").innerText = json;
}
```

**which outputs:**

```
{
term1: "definition",
term2: "definition",
term3: "definition",
term4: "definition"
}
```

This is okay, but I'd like to remove the special characters (`{",`)

Comment: Why don't you just loop over it and display it the way you want??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Us Object.entries and map to format the data how you want to display it.

```js
let dict = {
    term1: "definition 1",
    term2: "definition 2",
    term3: "definition 3",
    term4: "definition 4"
}

const str = Object.entries(dict).map(([key, value]) => `${key}: ${value}`).join("<br/>");

document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Seems like you really want a definition list

```js
let dict = {
  term1: "definition 1",
  term2: "definition 2",
  term3: "definition 3",
  term4: "definition 4"
}

const str = Object.entries(dict).map(([key, value]) => `<dt>${key}</dt><dd>${value}</dd>`).join('');

document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = str;
```

```css
dt::after {
  content: ":"
}

dt {
  display: inline-block;
}

dd {
  display: inline;

}

dd:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<dl id="out"></dl>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much. I did not know that existed.